# Load 2 solutions in Visual Studio .NET IDE

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to load more than one solution in the Visual Studio .NET IDE at once, so that both solutions appear in the Solution Explorer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Visual Studio can only load one solution at a time. There's a [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/106388/open-multiple-solutions) suggestion on this very topic.

What you *can* do, though, (aside from an obvious option of opening several instances of Visual Studio) is to "Add Existing" project to either solution, or create an ubersolution which will include them both.

Answer (score 0):

You can "add existing" picking .sln file type to current solution
or you can try to automate the process you can try playing around with this tool (might make sense if you have to do it repeatedly):

http://code.google.com/p/merge-solutions/